# Implementing Functor Instance for `ITree`

Tags: haskell, tree

Looking at this Typeclassopedia [exercise](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Typeclassopedia#Functor), I typed out `foldTree` on the following type:

```
data ITree a = Leaf (Int -> a) | Node [ITree a]
```

And my implementation of `Functor`:

```
instance Functor (ITree) where
    fmap = iTreeMap

iTreeMap :: (a -> b) -> ITree a -> ITree b
iTreeMap f (Leaf x)  = Leaf $ fmap f x   
iTreeMap f (Node xs) = Node $ map (iTreeMap f) xs
```

Please critique its signature, correctness and style.

Answer (score 1):

This looks mostly fine to me. If you wrote this code in a real codebase, I would not have any major qualms with it. Here are some nitpicks.

- The strangest thing to me was just the way you defined a separate function, `iTreeMap`, then used that as the definition of `fmap`. I would just define `fmap` directly within the body of the instance definition—no need to give it a separate name.
- The parentheses around `ITree` in the instance head are redundant. You could just write `Functor ITree` instead.
- Given that the value inside of a `Leaf` is a function, the use of the function instance of `fmap` within the definition of `iTreeMap` is a bit of genericism that I think is unnecessary. I would probably just use `(.)` and make the composition explicit, but that’s really personal preference.

With those above changes in place, the instance would look like this:

```
data ITree a = Leaf (Int -> a) | Node [ITree a]

instance Functor ITree where
  fmap f (Leaf x) = Leaf $ f . x
  fmap f (Node xs) = Node $ map (fmap f) xs
```

However, in real code, I wouldn’t actually do that at all. With the `DeriveFunctor` language extension, you could just ask GHC to write the `Functor` instance for you. Therefore, in *real* Haskell code, I would probably just write this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}

data ITree a = Leaf (Int -> a) | Node [ITree a]
  deriving (Functor)
```

But that’s probably against the spirit of the exercise. :)